# Make user input start with either "BR" or "BT"

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have an input field and I would like for it to check if the input entered starts with either "BR" or "BT". So for example BR1234 would be valid but JH1234 would not be valid. At the moment I can only get it to check "BR" and not "BT".

This is the code  I have so far:

```
 if (ID.indexOf('BR') === 0) || (ID.indexOf('BT') === 0){
}
else {
ID = "Invalid ID"
document.getElementById('ID').innerHTML = ID
return false;
```

Comment: Misplaced braces. You must be getting Syntax Error. Use `if (ID.indexOf('BR') === 0 || ID.indexOf('BT') === 0) {`

Comment: Try this (I have used Jquery):
https://jsfiddle.net/anupam_001/mqugLkhg/

Answer (score 2):

Check that you have the proper parentheses in the right positions. The condition for your `if` statement only contains `ID.indexOf('BR') === 0` because you already closed the parenthesis for it.

```
if (ID.indexOf('BR') === 0 || ID.indexOf('BT') === 0) {
    // ...
}
```

You can also use [`String.prototype.startsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) to check if a string starts with the desired string.

```
if (ID.startsWith('BR') || ID.startsWith('BT')) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript [startsWith](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_startswith.asp) method. Check if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `if(ID.test(/^(B(R|T))/)==true){//do stuff}` Remember your old friend RegExp.